# Shell: How to compare two Time strings and return difference in minutes?

Tags: shell, sh

I have two time strings

```
current_utc_time=`date +"%H%M" -u`
output will be 0848
sch_time=`date +"18%M" -u`
output will be 1848
```

How do I calculate the time difference in minutes between these two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your times to epoch and calculate seconds. I assume that you don't get your times from `date` because if so you can just format with `"+%s"` to get the epoch time immediately. The answer assumes you just have two strings with `%H%M`.

So, assign your strings with the timestamp (hour and minute)

```sh
current_utc_time=$(date +"%H%M")
sch_time=$(date +"18%M")
```

Convert to unix timestamp.

**macOS**

```sh
epoch_current=$(date -j -f "%H%M" "$current_utc_time" +%s)
epoch_sch=$(date -j -f "%H%M" "$sch_time" +%s)
```

**Linux**

```sh
epoch_current=$(date --date "$current_utc_time" +%s)
epoch_sch=$(date --date "$sch_time" +%s)
```

Calculate your diff (in minutes).

```sh
diff_in_minutes=$(( ($epoch_sch - $epoch_current) / 60 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

t1=`date +"%H%M" -u`

t2=`date +"18%M" -u`

## Compute the difference in dates in seconds

let "tDiff=$t2-$t1"

## Compute the approximate minute difference

let "hDiff=$tDiff/60"